# Model-building function in Keras Tuner did not return a valid Keras Model instance

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-tuner

I am trying to learn CNN following Krish naik Youtube tutorial in one program i am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model-building function did not return a valid Keras Model instance, found <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fd882393b38>
```

my code is given below

```
import keras.datasets
fashion=keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=fashion.load_data()

x_train=x_train/255.00
x_test=x_test/255.00
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2],1)
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],x_test.shape[2],1)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Flatten,Dropout,Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
def build_knn(hp):
    models=Sequential()
    models.add(Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv2d_1',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),
                      kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv1_kernal',values=[3,5]),
                      activation='relu',
                      input_shape=(28,28,1)
                                    ))
    models.add(Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv2d_1',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),
                      kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv1_kernal',values=[3,5]),
                      activation='relu'
                                    ))
    models.add(Flatten())
    models.add(Dense(hp.Int('neural1',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),activation='relu'))
    models.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
    models.compile(optimizer=Adam(hp.Choice('learning_rate',values=[1e-2,1e-3])),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                 )
    return models
from kerastuner import RandomSearch
from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters
tuner_search=RandomSearch(build_knn,objective='val_accuracy',max_trials=5,directory='jupyterfiles',project_name='krish_naik_fashion_mnist')
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not *very* clear in the [project site](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner), but is indeed mentioned that Keras Tuner is (emphasis added):

> A hyperparameter tuner for Keras, **specifically** for `tf.keras` with TensorFlow 2.0.

In other words, it works for `tf.keras`, but **not** for the stand-alone version of Keras, which you seem to be using here.

Indeed, adapting the basic example from the project site linked above, but changing the imports to use stand-alone Keras, replicates the error you report:

```
!pip install -U keras-tuner

import keras
from keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch

def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step=32),
                           activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=3,
    directory='my_dir',
    project_name='helloworld')
```

Result:

```
RuntimeError: Model-building function did not return a valid Keras Model instance, found <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fd882393b38>
```

But just by changing the imports to use `tf.keras` instead, i.e.:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch
```

the same code above runs OK without error.

So, you should change the imports shown here to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,Flatten,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

and you should be fine (provided of course that you use Tensorflow 2.0 indeed).

I have just opened a relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/311), advising that they include this clarification explicitly in a visible position.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply i will try in this ways

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzLAdpqm35E&list=PLZoTAELRMXVPGU70ZGsckrMdr0FteeRUi&index=27 i was follow that tutorial and he use same format which you suggest me , but i think i can also do that in above way but it was not working